# JavaScript: How to to update the value html table cell when data in local storage is updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a separate javascript code which is fetching data from api and inserting in browsers localStorage.

API is fetching ETA data and saving in localStorage as `id_ETA`(e.g 12342_ETA) key.

When the values in local storage gets updated then my html table ETA column values should also get updated without refreshing the page.

Right now I need to refresh the entire page in order to view the updated ETA in the html.

HTML Table:

```
<div class="container">     
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Arrival Address</th>
    <th>Departure Address</th>
    <th>ETA</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<script>

var data = getPlanData(); 
<div class="container">     
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Arrival Address</th>
<th>Departure Address</th>
<th>ETA</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['id']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['arrival']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['departure']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['arrival']+"</td>");
if (localStorage.getItem(data[i]['id']+'_ETA'))
{
document.write("<td>"+localStorage.getItem(data[i]['id']+'_ETA')+"</td>");
}
else
{
document.write("<td>-</td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
</script>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

getPlanData():

```
function getPlanData() {
    localData = localStorage.getItem('plan');
    result = csvToJSON(localData);
    return result;
}
```

Note: ETA is coming from separate API
Is there a way to update the ETA column when there is new ETA value in localStorage without refreshing the page?

Comment: Please may you update your example? It's currently full of errors. Make sure it is a [mcve].

Comment: Also please post getPlanData();  -

Comment: So what is WRITING to localStorage. I thought it was getPlanData. Please post all relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming getPlanData() does the writing to localStorage, you need to do two things

1. Don't use document.write, certainly not after load since it wipes the page
2. save to localStorage in getPlanData() AND
3. call this update with the data in the getPlanData function -  this script can be copied to the head of the document inside script tags and called as `update(data)`

```js
const update = data => { 

  const html = data.map(item => (
`<tr>
  <td>${item.id}</td>
  <td>${item.arrival}</td>
  <td>${item.departure}</td>
  <td>${item.arrival}</td>
  <td>${localStorage.getItem(item.id+"_ETA") || "-"}</td>
</tr>`));
  document.querySelector(".table tbody").innerHTML=html.join("")
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Arrival Address</th>
        <th>Departure Address</th>
        <th>ETA</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you post an example of your data, I am sure we can find a better way to get the ETA than `localStorage.getItem(item.id+"_ETA")`

UPDATE: You CAN do

```
var data = getPlanData(); 
update(data)
```